# What is the difference between transferring and making a payment on a credit card?

Tags: credit-card, payment, transfer

I have a CitiBank Mastercard. I have been paying the balance back to $0 regularly by transferring money from the checking account to the credit card. I notice there is also an option to "Make a payment" instead, but since I transfer the money regularly, the payment is usually "$0".

Is there a difference between transferring money and making a payment? Will this affect my interest paid or my credit score?

Comment: **How** have you been "*transferring money from the checking account to the credit card*"?

Comment: And is your checking account also at CiiBank?

Comment: Lastly, I think you're overthinking this.  "(T)ransferring money from the checking account to the credit card" **is** making a payment.  There's just more than one way to get from Here to There.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the "Make a Payment" icon, it takes you to your list of Payees.  These are external accounts.

When you click pay the "Pay Citi Cards" icon, it takes you to "Make A Transfer" which takes you to "Select Accounts".   This is where you want to be. Note that the first screen was PAY and the second screen was TRANSFER.

An alternative route is to click "Payments and Transfers" and then click "Your Citi Accounts"  which takes you to 
"Select Accounts" which again is where you want to be.

The terms Payment and Transfer are synonymous here.  No, there is no difference between transferring money and making a payment on the Cit web site.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a difference between transferring money and making a payment?

"Make a payment" probably involves an *external* bank account rather than your Citi checking account.

> Will this affect my interest paid or my credit score?

No. Your credit report does not indicate *how* your balance was paid.

Comment: When I click "Make a payment" it gives me options to move money from the checking account, just the name is different from the other method "Transfer". I'm just worried that by using "Transfer" instead of "Payments" my credit score will reflect having not made payments.

Comment: You're still paying your balance down, which is the important point. It will still count as a "payment".

Comment: @Village: You aren't responsible for CItiBank's poor user interface design.  I doubt that credit reporting companies look at more than outstanding balances, and perhaps late payments.  Still, if it bothers you, just use the "Payments" option :-)

Comment: It's not a poor interface design.  If you want to pay the credit card bill, one has several choices of how to pay it.  You can pay it by using a linked  external account (which is an incoming payment by transfer) or you can transfer money internally from another Citi account to pay the credit card bill.  The 3rd method of payment is to have Citi mail a check to pay a bill but that isn't relevant for Citi to Citi. It's all very straight forward and one of the easiest bull pay  systems that I have ever used.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: Having a "transfer" option in two different places is confusing interface design, obviously, since it has confused the OP.  Nor do I understand why there should be a distinction between Citi accounts and non-Citi accounts as a payment source.

Comment: @jamesqf  - So as a non user, the options that you cannot see confuses you?  The distinction between Citi accounts and non-Citi accounts as a payment source is made because payment to and from non-Citi accounts is an external transfer from an outside account whereas movement of money from one Citi account to another is an internal transfer.  I don't think that's something that's very hard for you to understand.  In every bank's bill pay that I have used, it's the same 'distinction'.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: I wouldn't say that I am a non-user, since I do have Citi credit cards, though not any other kind of account.  Whether I'd be confused is moot: my point is that the OP is confused, therefore Citi's UI is confusing for at least some people. QED.

Comment: The OP has been paying his bills without difficulty, His his question entailed  wondering if the using  the menu that includes Transfer is the same thing as using the menu  labeled Pay.  Since they both eventually take you to the same place on the web site, the end result is the same. PAID! As for your non confusion, even though you don't have nor do you use Cit's online bill pay,  you're not a non-user because you have Citi credit cards.   Yep, that  clears everything up.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, when you 'make a payment'. This means you can use a number of sources; bank accounts, e-checks, debit cards etc. If you already have an account with them and it states "transfer payment". It means you are transferring payment from one account (a checking/debit held with Citibank) to another account, in your case - a credit card line.